# Create Drag & Drop, Destory, Save Re-create - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

Ok, I have an issue with drag and drop.

What they do, they click a button, it initializes the whole drag and drop.

```
function sortElements() {               
    // Place droppable elements
    var x = 0;
    $("#content-body div[data-type='column'],#content-body div[data-type='carousel']").each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        if(x == 0){
            el.before('<div class="neoDroppableEle" id="neoDroppableEle-' + x + '"><\/div>');
            x++;
        }
        el.addClass('edit_el').after('<div class="neoDroppableEle" id="neoDroppableEle-' + x + '"><\/div>');
        x++;
        el.append('<div class="drag-handle"><i class="fa fa-arrows"></i></div>');

        var w = el.width();
        el.css('width',w+'px');
    });

    $("#content-body div[data-type='insertable']").each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        el.prepend('<div class="neoDroppableEle" id="neoDroppableEle-' + x + '"><\/div>');
        x++;
    });

    // Swap entire columns
    $("#content-body div[data-type='column']").draggable({
        refreshPositions: true,
        helper: "clone",
        handle:'.drag-handle',
        appendTo: "body",
        zIndex: 10000,
        start: function( event, ui ) {
            $(".neoDroppableEle").addClass('dragging');
        },
        stop: function( event, ui ) {
            $(".neoDroppableEle").removeClass('dragging');
        }
    });

    $(".neoDroppableEle").droppable({
        accept: "div[data-type='column']",
        tolerance: "pointer",
        hoverClass: "focus_in",
        activeClass: "focus_in_active",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            cur_ele = this.id;
            var el = ui.draggable;
            var html = el.html();
            el.remove();            
            $("#" + cur_ele).replaceWith('<div class="row" data-type="column">'+html+'</div>');
        }
    });

    // Swap individual photos within columns
    $("#content-body div[data-type='imagewrap']").each(function(){
        $(this).draggable({ 
            revert: "invalid", 
            helper: "clone" ,
            zIndex: 10001,
        });
        $(this).droppable({
            accept: "div[data-type='imagewrap']",
            activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
            hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
            drop: function( event, ui ) {       
                var draggable = ui.draggable, droppable = $(this);
                draggable.swap(droppable);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

When they are done, they click the button again.

```
function sortElementsComplete() {
    $(".ui-droppable").droppable("destroy");
    $(".ui-draggable").draggable("destroy");
    $(".edit_el").removeAttr('style').removeClass('edit_el');
    $(".neoDroppableEle").remove();
    $(".drag-handle").remove();
}
```

This all runs and works great!

But now I am tryng to save the HTML code after each drop for undo's. And when I save the undo, I need to remove all additional classes and elements my function to drag and drop add's. Because they may not be in the sorting area when they click undo and do not want drag handles and my borders I set up as visual aids just appearing.

So now I have:

```
$(".neoDroppableEle").droppable({
    accept: "div[data-type='column']",
    tolerance: "pointer",
    hoverClass: "focus_in",
    activeClass: "focus_in_active",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        cur_ele = this.id;
        var el = ui.draggable;
        var html = el.html();
        el.remove();            
        $("#" + cur_ele).replaceWith('<div class="row" data-type="column">'+html+'</div>');

        setTimeout(function(){
            sortElementsComplete();
            editor_add();
        },1000);
    }
});
```

The above with the timeout code always fails with:

> Error: cannot call methods on droppable prior to initialization;
>   attempted to call method 'destroy'

How so? It IS initialized and running. After the drop I should be able to destroy it, make my save and rebuild it. Using disable gives the same error. To me the error makes no sense.

After editor_add() is ran, it re-builds whatever they were doing, in this case it will fire sortElements(); after the save.

But the below runs fine?

```
// Swap individual photos within columns
$(this).droppable({
    accept: "div[data-type='imagewrap']",
    activeClass: "ui-state-hover",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-active",
    drop: function( event, ui ) {       
        var draggable = ui.draggable, droppable = $(this);
        draggable.swap(droppable);
        setTimeout(function(){
            sortElementsComplete();
            editor_add();
        },250);
    }
});
```

It will error if I do not have the timeout above. Seems 250 is the min, anything lower it errors. But the first one will not ever work, no matter how long or short I make the timeout.

Really hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if I used

```
    var draggable = ui.draggable, droppable = $(this);
    draggable.swap(droppable);
```

On it instead it would work. o.O